# Nonboolean receiver--proceed for truth

Tags: exception, smalltalk

I have a smalltalk method:

```
isInvalid
    |tmp|
    tmp := super isInvalid.
    tmp ifTrue: [^ True].
    ^ instanceVar isNil.
```

I am getting an exception: `Unhandled exception: NonBoolean receiver--proceed for truth` thrown on the assignment to temp. I am very sure that `super isInvalid` returns a Boolean object, so I think I am misunderstanding what this exception means.  Does anybody else happen to know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long time ago, a worked in Smalltalk fulltime. Good to see that it is alive ...

I see the following error in your code:

- You use as a return value the value `True`, which is (in Smalltalk) the class with only value `true`.
- You have to use instead the value `true` which is one of the (I think) predefined objects from the VM of Smalltalk which are `true`, `false`, `nil`.
- An even better solution would be:

  ```
  ^ super isInvalid or: [instanceVar isNil]
  ```

  This replaces the whole body or your message, by the boolean expression (which is all the time `true` or `false`, no possibility for errors). (Thank's to Fabian for the correct method `or:`.)

So use the right return value, and the error message will go away.

By the way, the error message `Unhandled exception: NonBoolean receiver--proceed for truth` is some kind of debugging help, it allows you to proceed, so that you are able to develop faster ... Never saw that again in any other language ...

Comment: Thanks. I was working in Python this morning where the boolean values are True and False. That did it.

Comment: mliebelt is right, however, to reflect the same semantics of your example (w.r.t. lazy evaluation) would be `^ super isInvalid or: [instanceVariable isNil]` (`||` evaluates both values every time, `#or:` does not)

Comment: i don't think that this is true. 2 cases: first one: `super isInvalid == true` ==> jump out by returning nil, no evaluation of the rest. second one: `super isInvalid == false` ==> Evaluate `instanceVar isNil` and return the result. This is exactly what `||` does.

Comment: @mliebelt no, it does not. `|` is a binary message that requieres *both* its arguments to evaluated. `#or:` is a keyword message that takes a block that is *only* evaluated if the receiver evaluates to `false`. Try it: `([Transcript show: '1'. true] value) | ([Transcript show: '2'. true] value)` will print `12` while `([Transcript show: '1'. true] value) or: [[Transcript show: '2'. true] value]` will only print `1`. Also I just saw it is `|` rather than `||`, which Smalltalk are you refering to?

Comment: Sorry, but there are 2 messages available: `|` that you have used that evaluates both parts; `||` which I have used that evaluates only the second part if the first returns `false` (at least I thought that). I'm talking from Smalltalk-80 (ParcPlace), but my knowledge is more than 10 years ago. When I looked at the book `||` was not part of the protocol, but `or:` is. So I will replace it with your method, to be sure that it is the correct method.